# How to open iOS share menu via HTML

Tags: html, ios, url-scheme

I'm currently working on a webpage and I'd like to implement a function to share this website to friends of the website-visitor.

Therefore I've integrated the Whatsapp-sharing URL Scheme.

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=text-to-share" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">
share-button
</a>
```

But there is a better way in iOS - I'd like to open the iOS-share-menue:

[iOS sharing-interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RD8cx.jpg)

Do you know, if there is any possibility to open this?
The iOS-Amazon-App does this within the product-pages.

I'm looking forward to your answers.

best regards,
Christoph

Answer (score 6):

Google has introduced the Web Share API for Web applications in Chrome. I think your problem is similar to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42081215/4711785

Comment: Hi,

thank you for your answer, this helped me a little.

Finally I solved my problem by using the URL-Scheme of each service, which I wanted to implement:


`<a href="mailto:?body=TEXT&subject=SUBJECT">Mail</a>
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=text" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">whatsapp</a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=URL">facebook Desktop</a>
<a href="fb-messenger://share/?link=URL&app_id=APP-ID">Facebook Messenger -> Mobile</a>`



Full example [here](http://www.hochzeits-fotograf-graz.at/)

Comment: I'm glad you solved the problem. URL-Scheme is the preferred solution. It can also be done with this library if necessary: https://github.com/eusonlito/jquery.applink

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a page which provides information on how this can be done and also a link to an example of this working...

(I have not copied the code from the article or the W3C source into my answer in case this is some sort of copyright violation)

https://w3c.github.io/web-share/

I have tested this on safari, chrome, and edge on IOS and macOS as of Oct 2022 and it worked perfectly...

I also tested it on the Opera browser running on a Huawei phone running their OS (not android) and again it invoked the OS'es share menu...

I fully expect this to work just as well on Windows and Android devices but I don't have any to test with...

Info and code to make it work: [Web.dev article](https://web.dev/web-share/)

and,

An example page you can use to test your device/browser...

[open device share menu using web page button demo](https://w3c.github.io/web-share/demos/share-files.html)